importrange function deletes 0 at the end
I got master sheet
There is all product codes and names with all the data.
Problem is when I use =importrange 
(https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ijB6rAPB-aL5-NPMmZoVOQ4fRdaZn-owoeESc2-ArLE/edit#gid=0) in other sheet some codes like 130.20, zero gets deleted and code appears as 130.2 and then formulas like vlookup dont work.
I tried formating as plain text it does not fix a promblem.
I tried formating as plain text and it only help in first sheet where data is paster but when i use =importrange 0 at the end get deleted.

Welcome to Stack Overflow. While links to external resources, in this case links to Google spreadsheet, might be helpful, questions on this site should be self-contained. Please [edit] the question to add all the relevant details directly into the question body.


The issue could be due to the reason that your importrange is pointing to a totally different sheet (1c2rLyFnlBIaGq092aFXbkoQH4U9drBjKW58GGqG_Ois) and not the master sheet(1n1vkc2uLpR9mNUA2hWXCNjJxN6cP05FvLF9o0Aledys) you added here in the question, which also has the column_B formatted to plain_text
Try with:
=importrange("1n1vkc2uLpR9mNUA2hWXCNjJxN6cP05FvLF9o0Aledys", "sheet1!B1:N8888")


It is different link because i made i copy for stackoverflow to now show my original sheets. But then I added second link and then first again it worked. Somehow google sheets do not refresh data properly.
Thank you very much, because of you I fixed it.
